# 500 Internal Server Error xampp codeignider and google adwords?

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp, http-status-code-500

when i try to execute a module that need to use google adwords tha website don't do anything so i see in the inspect the element and say that have a 500 Internal Server Error, i search o sometimes say the is temporal error butt have two days with same error, so i read that maybe is xampp and permitions so i modificate the 
httpd.conf, i change the ports i wirte the next code

`<Directory />
    AllowOverride All (also i tried with none)
    Require all granted
</Directory>`

i see the file hots in windows and set the 127.0.0.1 ....

i try to debug in app and i see that can pass in the next lines

```
$this->load->library('Google_adwords');
        $objGoogleAdword = new Google_adwords();
```

I see the xampp php log

and see this error

> [Wed Oct 11 13:22:14.132305 2017] [core:notice] [pid 1524:tid 576] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
>   [Wed Oct 11 13:22:14.135264 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1524:tid 576] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 8216
>   [Wed Oct 11 13:22:15.475520 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 8216:tid 520] AH01909: www.example.com:444:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>   [Wed Oct 11 13:22:15.747771 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 8216:tid 520] AH01909: www.example.com:444:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>   [Wed Oct 11 13:22:15.832788 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8216:tid 520] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

well i don't know why doen't works some idea?

Comment: www.example.com ? do you have a self-signed cert?

Comment: i don't know I think no but, What is a self-signed cert used for?, other thing that it's curios is the project is share in github and the others coworkers works fine the website